# drop all df2.columns from another df (pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame specific)

Tags: pyspark

I have a large DF (`pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`) that is a result of multiple joins, plus new columns being created by using a combination of inputs from different DFS, including DF2.

I want to drop all DF2 columns from DF after I'm done with the join/creating new columns based on DF2 input.
`drop()` doesn't accept list - only a string or a Column.

I know that `df.drop("col1", "col2", "coln")` will work but I'd prefer not to crowd the code (if I can) by listing those 20 columns.

Is there a better way of doing this in pyspark dataframe specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
drop_cols = df2.columns
df = df.drop(*drop_cols)
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? This is brilliant! Thank you 过过招!`drop_cols` is a list, does `*` change values in the list to`Column` or a `string`?

Comment: Asterisk import all parameters as tuples, it is to enumerate all column names of df2. If you find it helpful, can you upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: Your answer is very useful. I tried voting but because I've just created stackoverflow account, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.